# Is it possible to further reduce the cost of the request with Google sheets api v4 in setValue and setNumberFormat?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, batch-request

Now I use the code below to format and insert values.

```
function AddName () {
  const range1 = ['Q4:Q','S4:S','U4:U','W4:W','Y4:Y','AA4:AA','AC4:AC','AE4:AE',
  'AG4:AG','AI4:AI','AK4:AK','AM4:AM','AO4:AO','AQ4:AQ','AS4:AS','AU4:AU','AW4:AW','AY4:AY','BA4:BA',
  'BC4:BC','BE4:BE','BG4:BG','BI4:BI','BK4:BK','BM4:BM','BO4:BO','BQ4:BQ','BS4:BS','BU4:BU','BW4:BW',
  'BY4:BY','CA4:CA','CC4:CC','CE4:CE','CG4:CG','CI4:CI','CK4:CK','CM4:CM','CO4:CO','CQ4:CQ','CS4:CS',
  'CU4:CU','CW4:CW','CY4:CY','DA4:DA','DC4:DC','DE4:DE','DG4:DG','DI4:DI','DK4:DK','DM4:DM','DO4:DO',
  'DQ4:DQ','DS4:DS','DU4:DU','DW4:DW','DY4:DY','EA4:EA','EC4:EC','EE4:EE','EG4:EG','EI4:EI','EK4:EK',
  'EM4:EM','EO4:EO'];
  range1.reverse().forEach(c => sheet.getRange(c).setNumberFormat('0.00%'));
  const range = ['Q1','S1','U1','W1','Y1','AA1','AC1','AE1','AG1','AI1','AK1',
  'AM1','AO1','AQ1','AS1','AU1','AW1','AY1','BA1','BC1','BE1','BG1','BI1','BK1','BM1','BO1','BQ1',
  'BS1','BU1','BW1','BY1','CA1','CC1','CE1','CG1','CI1','CK1','CM1','CO1','CQ1','CS1','CU1','CW1',
  'CY1','DA1','DC1','DE1','DG1','DI1','DK1','DM1','DO1','DQ1','DS1','DU1','DW1','DY1','EA1','EC1',
  'EE1','EG1','EI1','EK1','EM1','EO1'];
  range.reverse().forEach(c => sheet.getRange(c).setValue('% наценки'));
 }
```

Is it possible to further reduce the cost of the request and speed up the script?
When formatting a lot of files, it will save me a lot of time

Comment: is there something between the columns? for example `EO` and `EM`; or at least on the first row?

Comment: @Adelin Yes, there are other columns in between that have data

Comment: I believe the new answers you got below are much better than my solution. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

#### Modification points:

- In this case, I thought that when RepeatCellRequest and UpdateCellsRequest of the batchUpdate in Sheets API are used, the process cost might be reduced a little.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set the variables of `spreadsheetId`, `sheetName` and `ranges`. `ranges` is from your script. When you want to more ranges, please add them to the array.

```
function myFunction() {
  const spreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  // Please set the ranges. In this sample, a part of your ranges is used. So please modify this for your actual situation.
  const ranges = ['Q4:Q','S4:S','U4:U',,,];

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const rangeList = sheet.getRangeList(ranges).getRanges();
  const requests = rangeList.flatMap(r => [
    {repeatCell:{cell:{userEnteredFormat:{numberFormat:{type:"PERCENT",pattern:"0.00%"}}},range:{sheetId:sheetId,startRowIndex:r.getRow() - 1,startColumnIndex:r.getColumn() - 1,endColumnIndex:r.getColumn() + r.getNumColumns() - 1},fields:"userEnteredFormat"}},
    {updateCells:{rows:[{values:[{userEnteredValue:{stringValue:"%наценки"}}]}],range:{sheetId:sheetId,startRowIndex:0,endRowIndex:1,startColumnIndex:r.getColumn() - 1,endColumnIndex:r.getColumn() + r.getNumColumns() - 1},fields:"userEnteredValue"}}
  ]);
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, spreadsheetId);
}
```

#### Note:

- In this modified script, when the Spreadsheet has the columns "A" to "Z", when the column "AA" is used, an error like `exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1000, max columns: 26` occurs. So please be careful this. Before you use this script, please add columns to the sheet for your `ranges`.

#### References:

- [RepeatCellRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#repeatcellrequest)
- [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest)

Answer (score 1):

If the columns of choice do not have a specific pattern. For example change the format for every 2 columns or something like that then I think your only option is to hardcopy them.

- Since you are looking for performance, consider doing the operation for `range1` not for the full column, but only until the last row with content. This will reduce the cost of your script if there are many rows in the sheet.

**Replace:**

```
range1.reverse().forEach(c => sheet.getRange(c).setNumberFormat('0.00%'));
```

**with:**

```
range1.reverse().forEach(c => sheet.getRange(c+sheet.getLastRow()).setNumberFormat('0.00%'));
```

Comment: This should work, but the extra rows have already been removed from spreadsheet

Comment: @АнтонКожевников I think that is the only improvement you can make..

Answer (score 1):

Use [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list#setNumberFormat(String)):

```
sheet.getRangeList(range1).setNumberFormat('0.00%');
sheet.getRangeList(range).setValue('% наценки'));
```