# Batch request removing empty rows and columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, batch-processing

I need to create a script which deletes all empty rows and columns (with no value in any cell of the row/column) from indicated sheet starting from 1 column/row, at the same time - using batch update. I have found a script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65717222/how-to-remove-empty-rows-and-columns-using-batch-request) and tried to suit it to my need.

I have modified it like below, but I do something wrong with function arguments (and probably something else).

```
function clear(){

  const sheetName = "Parser"; // Please set the sheet name.
  
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const sheetId = sh.getSheetValues;
var values = sh.getRange('B1:B').getValues();
  var requests = values.reduce((ar, value) => {
    var maxColumns = sh.getMaxColumns(); 
    var lastColumn = sh.getLastColumn();
    var maxRows = sh.getMaxRows(); 
    var lastRow = sh.getLastRow();
    if (lastRow == 0 && lastColumn == 0 && maxRows > 1 && maxColumns > 1) {
     ar.push({deleteDimension: {range: {sheetId: sheetId, dimension: "ROWS", startIndex: 1}}});
     ar.push({deleteDimension: {range: {sheetId: sheetId, dimension: "COLUMNS", startIndex: 1}}});
    }
Logger.log(ar);
   return ar;
  }, []);
    if (requests.length > 0) {
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests: requests}, id);
  }
};
```

Begging for help!

From:
[image]

to:
[image]

Comment: Please bear in mind that questions should be specific (you should delete the statement about the second batch update script). What do you mean by "but I do something wrong with function arguments (and probably something else)"? Are getting an error message, if so, add it textually. Also add some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Thank you, have deleted the second question and added an example. There are many different errors, the example I have provided - Logger.log(ar) results with endless "[]".

Comment: Thanks for you reply. By error message I meant an automatic message create by Google Apps Script with "Failed" status, but logs showing unexpected results are also helpful, so please [edit] the question to add that detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Try:

```
function clean() {

  const sheetName = "Parser"
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)

  const cleanRows = sheet.getDataRange()
                         .getValues()
                         .filter(row => !row.every(cell => cell === ``))

  const cleanCols = cleanRows[0].map((_, index) => cleanRows.flatMap(row => row[index]))
                                .filter(col => !col.every(cell => cell === ``))

  const values = cleanCols[0].map((_, index) => cleanCols.flatMap(row => row[index]))

  sheet.getDataRange().clearContent()
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values)

  if (sheet.getLastRow() !== sheet.getMaxRows()) sheet.deleteRows(sheet.getLastRow()+1, sheet.getMaxRows()-sheet.getLastRow())
  if (sheet.getLastColumn() !== sheet.getMaxColumns()) sheet.deleteColumns(sheet.getLastColumn()+1, sheet.getMaxColumns()-sheet.getLastColumn())
      
}
```

This will filter out all empty rows, rotate the array, filter out all empty 'columns', then rotate the array back and update the sheet.

```
function clear() {
    
  const sheetName = "Parser"
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName)
    
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, sheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent()

}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

### Clean() Result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, there is the error at the part: const cleanCols = rowsWithData[0], as rowsWithData is undefined.

Comment: Still there is the error regarding cleanRows[0] is undefined. The error is: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Are you able to update your question with a partial screenshot of your data? I've updated my post with how it looks on my end.

Comment: The script should start at A1 (there will be empty A1, A2, A3, then some between the filled ones like A11, A12 and also the rows on the end A100, A111.... Regarding columns, basically I need to delete the first column, but the script is slower when I do it separately, that is the reason I wanted to do it using batch update.

Comment: Updated to include A1, however, this should still work for you. With 900 rows x 900 columns it takes literally 1 second to run. Can I see an example of your sheet with data so I can better understand why it's not working for you?

Comment: I have added the example.

Comment: I see, using the same example it works fine on my end. Are you testing this in your sheet called "Parser" ?

Comment: @mishelles Updated to include screenshots of your provided example working.

Comment: I did, but after your last edit it seems to be working, actually the script does not delete the rows and columns in the beginning and the end. These are still empty and undeleted (is is visible on your screenshot too), however it is also very helpful for me like that too.

Comment: Would you like me to update the code to delete the unused rows and columns?

Comment: If it is not very much effor for you, It would be probably faster tha mine edit.